# How to calculate this limit by applying The Monotone Convergence Theorem?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_{[0,1]} 1-\arctan\left(\frac{x}{n}\right) d \lambda$$

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jlDx9.jpg)

Please look at the picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ask yourself if $\{f_n\}$ is a increasing sequence. If so, then you need to find a function $0\le f$ integrable such that $f_n\le f$ a.e.

Therefore, by Monotone Convergence Theorem, you can interchange limit with the integral.